# Does shared_ptr guarantee thread safety for the underlying object?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, shared-ptr, race-condition

**Problem**

I believe the following code should lead to runtime issues, but it doesn't. I'm trying to update the underlying object pointed to by the `shared_ptr` in one thread, and access it in another thread.

```
struct Bar {
    Bar(string tmp) {
        var = tmp;
    }
    string var;
};

struct Foo {
    vector<Bar> vec;
};

std::shared_ptr<Foo> p1, p2;
std::atomic<bool> cv1, cv2;

void fn1() {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < p1->vec.size() ; i++) {
        cv2 = false;
        cv1.wait(true);
        std::cout << p1->vec.size() << " is the new size\n";
        std::cout << p1->vec[i].var.data() << "\n";
    }
}

void fn2() {
    cv2.wait(true);
    p2->vec = vector<Bar>();
    cv1 = false;
}

int main()
{
    p1 = make_shared<Foo>();
    p1->vec = vector<Bar>(2, Bar("hello"));
    p2 = p1;

    cv1 = true;
    cv2 = true;
    
    thread t1(fn1);
    thread t2(fn2);
    
    t2.join();
    t1.join();
}
```

**Description**

weirdly enough, the output is as follows. prints the new size as 0 (empty), but is still able to access the first element from the previous vector.

```
0 is the new size
hello
```

Is my understanding that the above code is not thread safe correct? am I missing something?

OR

According to the docs

> All member functions (including copy constructor and copy assignment) can be called by multiple threads on different instances of shared_ptr without additional synchronization even if these instances are copies and share ownership of the same object.

Since I'm using `->`/`*` member functions, does it mean that the code is thread safe? This part is kind of confusing as I'm performing read and write simultaneously without synchronization.

Comment: No it does not.  But if you start the thread with a lambda and capture the shared pointer by value you can extend the lifetime of the object pointed to to the lifetime of the thread. Also try to avoid global variables (specially with threads).

Comment: As for the read/write synchronization you really need to make that threadsafe as well std::mutex/std::scoped_lock

Comment: The only part of `shared_ptr` that is thread-safe is the internal control block, the part that does the book-keeping like the reference count.

Comment: One cannot protect what one doesn't own and control. A pointer, or a pointer-like object, doesn't really own or control the pointed-to object; only deleting an object at some point isn't real control or ownership, as anyone can access the pointed-to object. Unlike say the memory blocks of a `deque`.

Answer (score 1):

As for the shared_ptr:
In general, you can call all member functions of DIFFERENT instances of the shared_ptr from multiple threads without synchronization. However, if you want to call these functions from multiple threads on the SAME shared_ptr instance then it may lead to a race condition. When we talk about thread safety guarantee in the case of shrared_ptr, it is only guaranteed for the internals of the shared_ptr as explained above NOT FOR THE underlying object.

Having that said, consider the following code and read the comments. You can also play with it here: https://godbolt.org/z/8hvcW19q9

```
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex widget_mutex;

class Widget
{
    std::string value;

public:
  void set_value(const std::string& str) { value = str; } 
};


//This is not safe, you're calling member function of the same instance, taken by ref
void mt_reset_not_safe(std::shared_ptr<Widget>& w)
{
    w.reset(new Widget());
}

//This is safe, you have a separate instance of shared_ptr
void mt_reset_safe(std::shared_ptr<Widget> w)
{
    w.reset(new Widget());
}

//This is not safe, underlying object is not protected from race conditions
void mt_set_value_not_safe(std::shared_ptr<Widget> w)
{
    w->set_value("Test value, test value");
}

//This is safe, we use mutex to safetly update the underlying object
void mt_set_value_safe(std::shared_ptr<Widget> w)
{
    auto lock = std::scoped_lock{widget_mutex};

    w->set_value("Test value, test value");
}


template<class Callable, class... Args>
void run(Callable callable, Args&&... args)
{
    auto th1 = std::thread(callable, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    auto th2 = std::thread(callable, std::forward<Args>(args)...);

    th1.join();
    th2.join();

}

void run_not_safe_reset()
{
    auto widget = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    run(mt_reset_not_safe, std::ref(widget));
}

void run_safe_reset()
{
    auto widget = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    run(mt_reset_safe, widget);
}

void run_mt_set_value_not_safe()
{
    auto widget = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    run(mt_set_value_not_safe, widget);
}

void run_mt_set_value_safe()
{
    auto widget = std::make_shared<Widget>();
    run(mt_set_value_safe, widget);
}

int main()
{
    //Uncommne to see the result

    // run_not_safe_reset();
    // run_safe_reset();

    // run_mt_set_value_not_safe();
    // run_mt_set_value_safe(); 
}
```